# Difference in time between strings

Tags: java

I was working on a coding challenge where the goal was to find the smallest time difference in a list of Strings. I gave up and looked at a solution which in all makes sense, but I'm confused on the method `parseTime`. Can anybody please explain this method?

As I see it, the two hours compared are subtracted and then multiplied by 60 (becuase 60 min in one hour?).
From that the minutes are compared and then I get lost.. Can anybody explain this as simple as possible?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"10:00am", "11:45pm", "5:00am", "12:01am"};
        int i = TimeDifference(strings);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static int TimeDifference(String[] strArr) {

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i=0; i<strArr.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<strArr.length; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    int time = parseTime(strArr[j], strArr[i]);
                    if (time < min) min = time;
                }
            }
        }
        return min;

    }

    private static int parseTime(String time1, String time2) {
        int time = (parseHour(time2) - parseHour(time1))*60;
        time += parseMin(time2) - parseMin(time1);
        if (isMorning(time2) != isMorning(time1)) {
            time += 12 *60;
        } else if (time <= 0 ) {
            time += 24 * 60;
        }

        return time;
    }

    private static int parseHour(String time) {
        int hour = Integer.valueOf(time.split(":")[0]);
        return ( hour == 12? 0: hour);
    }

    private static int parseMin(String time) {
        return Integer.valueOf(time.split(":")[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]",""));
    }

    private static boolean isMorning(String time) {
        String post = time.split(":")[1].replaceAll("[^a-z]","");
        return post.toLowerCase().equals("am");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the difference in hours are converted to minutes by multiplying by `60`. Then using `parseMin` the difference in minutes are added to it.

Now we need it check if it is `AM` or `PM`. Example : if the times were `10:30 am` and `1:35 pm`. The actual time difference is `+115` minutes.

After `parseHour` the `time` would have a value of `-600` ((1-10)*60). Then after `parseMin`, `time` would be `-595` (difference of 5 minutes added). Now we need to see if it is `AM` or `PM`. Since `time1` is `AM` and `time2` is `PM`, we add a difference of `12hrs`. This is because the same time in `AM` and `PM` would differ by 12hrs.
After this the `time` would be `(-605 + 720) = 115` minutes.

The case when `time<=0`. This is when `time2` is before `time1`. example `time1` be `10:35am` and `time2` be `10:30am`. So the question is - how much time would it take to **REACH** `10:30am` **FROM** `10:35am`. Since it is alreaddy `10:35am` and since we cannot go back in time, we need to wait till the next day(24 hrs) to reach `10:30am`. So we add `24*60 minutes` to the `time`, which would give `-5 + (24*60)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the last part `time <=0`

Answer (score 2):

Try to debug your code in your mind. Please check my comments below:

```
       int minutes = parseTime("10:00am", "11:45pm");

       private static int parseTime(String time1, String time2) {
            int minutes = (parseHour(time2) - parseHour(time1))*60;//(11 - 10) * 60 = 60 minutes
            minutes += parseMin(time2) - parseMin(time1); //60 + 45 - 0 = 105 minutes
            if (isMorning(time2) != isMorning(time1)) { // 10:00am is not morning but 11:45pm is morning
                minutes += 12 *60; //so we have to add 12 hours(12 * 60 minutes)
            } else if (minutes <= 0 ) {
                minutes += 24 * 60;
            }
    
            return minutes;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is about regular expressions (RegEx). Let's look at `11:45pm` as an example, and break up `parseTime`:

`int time = (parseHour(time2) - parseHour(time1))*60;`

The first line makes use of `parseHour`, which makes use of [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), which splits the string around matches of the given regular expression, `":"`, and then parses the string at index 0 as an integer.
The string `"11:45pm"` is split into a string array `{"11", "45pm"}`, and the integer `11` is returned.

`time += parseMin(time2) - parseMin(time1);`

The second line makes use of `parseMin`, which similarly splits the given string, but parses the string at index 1 instead. However, the string `"45pm"` cannot be parsed as an integer, because it contains the non-digits `"pm"`, so we use `replaceAll` to replace any non-digits with empty strings.
[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
`"[^0-9]"` matches any single character not present in `0-9`, which is all nondigits, so `"45pm".replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")` returns `"45"`, which is then parsed as an integer.

The rest has been answered by others already.